# How to COUNT(*) with GROUP BY in django

Tags: python, django

I would like to do the equivalent of following query in a Django QuerySet:

```
SELECT address, city, state, zip, COUNT(*)
FROM entries
GROUP BY address, city, state, zip
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Unfortunately, Django's Count() aggregate function requires a field, but I'm not counting any one individual field. Also, I can't use '*' as a field.

Is the only way to do this using .raw()?

Comment: Use the [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) method.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, although `count()` is correct in the general case, it doesn't work with `GROUP BY` - it returns a single value. This case is best handled through:

```
qs = Entries.objects.values('address', 'city', 'state', 'zip').annotate(entry_count=Count('id'))
```

That should count the number of ids and therefore the number of unique rows in each group.

For the `having` part, filtering on the annotation will do that:

```
qs = qs.filter(entry_count__gt=5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`QuerySet.count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count):

> A `count()` call performs a `SELECT COUNT(*)` behind the scenes, so you
>   should always use `count()` rather than loading all of the record into
>   Python objects and calling `len()` on the result (unless you need to
>   load the objects into memory anyway, in which case `len()` will be
>   faster).

Comment: The user's query uses `group by`, which `QuerySet.count()` does not respect.

Answer (score 1):

```
queryset = Entries.objects.values('address', 'city', 'state', 'zip').annotate(cnt=Count('*')).filter(cnt__gt=5)
```

it will work well. * is better than other fields.